# How to password protect my excel sheet after saving them using vb script

Tags: vba, excel, vbscript

In my code I have used vb scripting to take input from the user using inputbox and save it in excel also it is saving the data in newline plus it is also keeping the old entries but I want to password protect my excel sheet after saving it after taking values from inputbox througfh vb scripting I have tried it in my code below but it is not working kindly help me out I have highlighted the lines of the code where I tried to implement my logic to password protect the excel sheet after saving it using ** sign

```
sInput = InputBox("Enter your name")

MsgBox ("You entered:" & sInput)

sInput1 = InputBox("Enter your name")

MsgBox ("You entered:" & sInput)

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\rrr.xlsx")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

**objExcel.sheet(1).unprotect= "saurabh"**
Set rg = objExcel.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

lr = rg.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With rg
    .Offset(lr, 0).Value = sInput
    .Offset(lr, 1).Value = sInput1 

End With


objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
**objExcel.sheet(1).protect= "saurabh"**
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use below (protecting case):

```
objExcel.sheet(1).Protect Password:="YourPassword", DrawingObjects:=True, Contents:=True, Scenarios:=True _
, AllowSorting:=True, AllowFiltering:=True, AllowUsingPivotTables:=True
```

Unprotect

```
objExcel.sheet(1).UnProtect Password:="YourPassword"
```

Answer (score 0):

Hi it is working now below is the working code for that--

```
sInput = InputBox("Enter your name")

MsgBox ("You entered:" & sInput)

sInput1 = InputBox("Enter your name")

MsgBox ("You entered:" & sInput1)

Set objExcel = CreateObject("Excel.Application")
Set objWorkbook = objExcel.Workbooks.Open("C:\Users\saurabh.ad.sharma\Desktop\rrr.xlsx")

objExcel.Application.Visible = True

objExcel.Sheets(1).unprotect "saurabh"
Set rg = objExcel.Sheets(1).Range("A1")

lr = rg.CurrentRegion.Rows.Count

With rg
    .Offset(lr, 0).Value = sInput
    .Offset(lr, 1).Value = sInput1 

End With


objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
objExcel.Sheets(1).protect "saurabh"
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Save 
objExcel.ActiveWorkbook.Close

objExcel.Application.Quit
WScript.Echo "Finished."
WScript.Quit
```